# How to get the data from google app engine datastore into angular js which at client side?

Tags: java, javascript, google-app-engine, angularjs, gwt

I am new to the angularJS.Earlier we were developing our web application with the gwt at client side.
Now we decided to move to AngularJS from GWT because our application speed have became slow and also because of some of the awesome features of AngularJS. I have gone through the documents and did some practice about basic AngularJS.

In GWT, We used GWT-RPC mechanism to communicate with the server, but i could not be able to get mechanism that i have to communicate with the server in AngularJS. Please let me know procedure to deal with server to get, put, delete etc..data in AngularJS.

If possible please give me a link to get the sample project.

Any Suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 3):

you can use one of the three alternatives below

> > You have to use [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) to make a RESTFULL communication with the server thats the prefered way in angularJS

you can get started with [this](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2433-Using-RESTful-Controllers-In-An-AngularJS-Resource.htm)

as you are from java background i suggest you to see [AngularJS Example Using a Java RESTful Web Service](http://draptik.github.io/blog/2013/07/13/angularjs-example-using-a-java-restful-web-service/)

[`$http service`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http) is a core Angular service that facilitates communication with the remote HTTP servers via the browser's XMLHttpRequest object or via JSONP.

[`Restangular`](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular)  is an AngularJS service that simplifies common GET, DELETE, and UPDATE requests with a minimum of client code. It's a perfect fit for any WebApp that consumes data from a RESTful API.

Answer (score 2):

Nice article on how to leverage AngularJS with Google Cloud Platform and, in particular, Google Cloud Endpoints

[AngularJS + Cloud Endpoints: A Recipe for Building Modern Web Applications](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/angularjs-cloud-endpoints-recipe-for-building-modern-web-applications)